# Removing rogue webjob from Azure web application

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have an azure wep app, with a couple of web jobs running inside it. I noticed one of these webjobs was running old code. It is also impossible to remove it, it keeps running no matter what I do.

I have tried:
* Redeploying the code.
* Stopping the webjob
* Stopping the web app
* Deleting the web job.

Even after deletion, the webjob is still running, and consuming from its queue.

There is no web app anywhere that is running a webjob with that old code anymore.

I have a suspicion that the webjob is running inside a deployment slot, but all deployment slots were deleted, so I do not know how to confirm this.

On the kudu dashboard, the webjob is not present in the process explorer.

How do I get rid of this rogue webjob?

Comment: I have completely deleted the web app, and re created it. The web job still exists, and is running.

Comment: Are you sure its not running on another server (maybe outside of Azure)?  If your app service plan is deleted and you haven't accidentally deployed it to another subscription or environment I don't see any other option!

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no other place it is running. If this is the case however... changeing the access keys so that it can no longer access the queue should block it out. It will also block out the rogue webapp (hopefilly). I will report back.

Comment: maybe worth also checking your billing data and seeing where compute is being spent

Comment: There is no way it can run if that Web App was deleted. It must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: I regenerated the keys, so whatever it was, is now locked out. My suspicion is that one of the devs deployed a webjob into a web app they were not supposed to. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to get specific job by name and check job runs history via [WebJobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API), which could help you check whether job is indeed deleted/stopped. If the WebJob is deleted from current website, please make sure whether any other WebJob running on your other websites are consuming the queue. In addition please make sure whether [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-functions/) are being used. Of cause, the tasks outside of Azure could consuming queue is also possible. If you worry someone is performing your storage maliciously, as you said, you could try to regenerate your storage account keys, but you may need to re-sync the access keys with your applications/services that are dependent on the storage account.